# How to delete lines in file1 based on column match with file2

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have 2 files; `file1` and `file2`. File1 has many lines/rows and columns. File2 has just one column, with several lines/rows. All of the strings in `file2` are found in `file1`. I want to create a new file (`file3`), such that the lines in `file1` that contain the any of the strings in `file2` are deleted.

For example,

File1:

```
Sally ate 083 popcorn

Rick has 241 cars

John won 505 dollars

Bruce knows 121 people
```

File2:

```
083

121
```

Desired file3:

```
Rick has 241 cars

John won 505 dollars
```

Note that I do not want to enter the strings in file 2 into a command manually (the actual files are much larger than in the example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{p=""}FNR==NR{if(!/^$/){p=p$0"|"} next} $0!~substr(p, 1, length(p)-1)' file2 file1 > file3
```

---

`p=""` the variable treated as pattern containing all column values from `file2`

`FNR==NR` ensures that the next expression is performed for the first input file i.e. `file2`

`if(!/^$/){p=p$0"|"}` means: if it's not an empty line `!/^$/` (as it could be according to your input) concatenate pattern parts with `|` so it eventually will look like `083|121|`

`$0!~substr(p, 1, length(p)-1)` - checks if a line from the second input file(`file1`) is not matched with pattern(i.e. `file2` column values)

---

The `file3` contents:

```
Rick has 241 cars

John won 505 dollars
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
#cat f1
Sally ate 083 popcorn
Rick has 241 cars
John won 505 dollars
Bruce knows 121 people

#cat f2
083
121

#grep -vwf f2 f1
Rick has 241 cars
John won 505 dollars
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` suites your purpose better than a line editor

```
grep -v -f File2 File1 >File3
```

Comment: You may want to add `-w` option as well, to prevent partial matches.